# Como aplicar decorators que sejam classes em métodos de instância de outras classes?

Tags: python, decorator-pattern

Estou tentando implementar uma classe que seja um *method decorator* em python. A ideia é aplicá-la à métodos de outras classes. No entanto, ela está se perdendo quanto a referência `self` do método da classe anotada.

Fiz o seguinte MCVE para demonstrar o problema:

```
import traceback

class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.__wrapped = wrapped

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"PARÂMETROS: args = {args}, kwargs = {kwargs}")
        return self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

class Teste:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 123

    @Decorator
    def foo(self):
        return self.__x

x = Teste()

print("\nInvocando método de instância como se fosse estático.")
try:
    print(Teste.foo(x))
    print("Funcionou!")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()

print("\nInvocando método de instância diretamente.")
try:
    print(x.foo())
    print("Funcionou!")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

No código acima, eu criei a classe `Decorator` cujas instâncias devem ser aplicadas à métodos de outras classes como *method decorators*. A classe `Teste` é a que contém o método `foo` decorado. O código subsequente tenta invocar o método `foo` de `Teste` de duas formas diferentes (como se fosse um método estático e da forma usual como um método de instância).

Eis o resultado:

```
Invocando método de instância como se fosse estático.
PARÂMETROS: args = (<__main__.Teste object at 0x02BE0E90>,), kwargs = {}
123
Funcionou!

Invocando método de instância diretamente.
PARÂMETROS: args = (), kwargs = {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mcve.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(x.foo())
  File "mcve.py", line 9, in __call__
    return self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

O resultado demonstra que invocar `Teste.foo(x)` funciona, mas invocar `x.foo()` não funciona. Eu gostaria que métodos de instância fossem chamados como tal, independente do fato de eu ter aplicado um *method decorator* arbitrário nele. Nota-se que quando o método é chamado tal como um método de instância, a instância de `Teste` não está nem no `args` e nem no `kwargs`.

Também tentei isso daqui, mas novamente não funcionou:

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.__wrapped = wrapped

    def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"PARÂMETROS: args = {args}, kwargs = {kwargs}")
        return args[0].__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
```

Assim, pergunto:

- Como posso fazer um *method decorator* que seja uma classe de forma que uma chamada `x.foo()` funcione?
- Ou de outra forma, como posso "pescar" a referência a instância do método decorado (o `self` do `foo`) ao invés de pegar o `self` do próprio *decorator*?

**Adendo**

Imaginando que a classe `Decorator` seja assim:

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.__wrapped = wrapped

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"PARÂMETROS: args = {args}, kwargs = {kwargs}")
        return self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

    def bar(self):
        return 456
```

A ideia é que `print(x.foo.bar)` também imprima 456.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradeço muito ao Anderson Carlos Woss. Apesar da [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/395658/132) ter me indicado alguns caminhos, não permitia que eu acessasse coisas como `x.foo.bar`, e portanto ainda não era tudo o que eu precisava.

Pesquisando mais sobre o assunto, também considerei essa [resposta do Martijn Pieters no SO.en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/540552), que apesar de ser para uma pergunta bem diferente, há vários fatores similares a esta daqui.

Depois de quebrar bastante a cabeça por uns dias, cheguei a isso:

```
import traceback
from functools import wraps

class InnerDecorator:
    def __init__(self, real_self, wrapped, other):
        self.__real_self = real_self
        self.__wrapped = wrapped
        self.__other = other

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__real_self is None:
            print(f"PARÂMETROS (ESTÁTICO): args = {args}, kwargs = {kwargs}")
            return self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print(f"PARÂMETROS (INSTÂNCIA): self = {self.__real_self} args = {args}, kwargs = {kwargs}")
            return self.__wrapped(self.__real_self, *args, **kwargs)

    def other(self):
        return self.__other

class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.__wrapped = wrapped

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype = None):
        if self.__wrapped is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")

        @wraps(self.__wrapped)
        def interno():
            return InnerDecorator(obj, self.__wrapped, 77)
        return interno()

    def other(self):
        return self.__get__(None, None).other()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__get__(None, None)(*args, **kwargs)

@Decorator
def xoom(bar):
    return 500 + bar

class Teste:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x

    @Decorator
    def foo(self, bar):
        return self.__x + bar

print("\nInvocando método de instância como se fosse estático.")
try:
    x = Teste(3)
    print(Teste.foo(x, 30))
    print(Teste.foo.other())
    print("Funcionou!")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()

print("\nInvocando método de instância diretamente.")
try:
    x = Teste(5)
    print(x.foo(10))
    print(x.foo.other())
    print("Funcionou!")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()

print("\nInvocando funções.")
try:
    print(xoom(55))
    print(xoom.other())
    print("Funcionou!")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Eis a saída:

```
Invocando método de instância como se fosse estático.
PARÂMETROS (ESTÁTICO): args = (<__main__.Teste object at 0x02FD5990>, 30), kwargs = {}
33
77
Funcionou!

Invocando método de instância diretamente.
PARÂMETROS (INSTÂNCIA): self = <__main__.Teste object at 0x02FC0F90> args = (10,), kwargs = {}
15
77
Funcionou!

Invocando funções.
PARÂMETROS (ESTÁTICO): args = (55,), kwargs = {}
555
77
Funcionou!
```

Enfim, isso demonstra que o `@Decorator` pode ser aplicado em um método como se ele fosse estático, pode ser aplicado em um método de instância normal e também pode ser aplicado em uma função qualquer que não seja método de qualquer classe. Além disso, ele acrescenta uma propriedade `other` ao método decorado.

O principal ponto de melhoria é que foram necessárias duas classes para fazer isso, o `Decorator` e o `InnerDecorator` e há alguma duplicação de código entre elas. Mas já me dou por satisfeito e atingi o objetivo que buscava atingir.

Answer (score 4):

**Contextualização do erro**

O problema é que ao fazer o método decorado, o atributo `Teste.foo` passa a ser uma instância de `Decorator`, pois decorá-lo assim é equivalente ao fazer:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 123

    def _foo(self):
        return self.__x

    foo = Decorator(_foo)
```

E, portanto, quando você faz `Teste.foo(x)`, sendo `x` a sua instância, você na verdade estará fazendo o equivalente à:

```
Decorator.__call__(Teste.foo, x)
```

Sendo executado, assim, `self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)`, em que `self` será `Teste.foo`, `__wrapped` será o método `Teste._foo` e o valor de `x` passado entrará em `*args`. Desta forma, o resultado produzido será o equivalente a chamar `Teste._foo(x)`, que seria o mesmo que `x._foo()`, produzindo, assim, a saída esperada.

Enquanto, quando você faz `x.foo()`, os parâmetros mudam, pois será o mesmo que fazer `Decorator.__call__(x.foo)`. Como pode ver na implementação, o método `__call__` chamará o método decorado passando apenas `*args` e `**kwargs` e, como na chamada não é passado nada além da instância do decorador, esses valores serão uma lista vazia e um dicionário vazio respectivamente. Como consequência disso, ao invocar o método decorado em `self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)`, nenhum parâmetro será passado, o que gera o erro citado na pergunta, pois o parâmetro `self` é obrigatório visto que é um método de instância.

**Possível solução**

O que você pode fazer é utilizar uma *closure* no seu decorador de forma que, ao invés de fazer o atributo `Teste.foo` ser uma instância de `Decorator` você faz ele ser um *closure* definido por esta classe. Isso implica que quando você fizer a chamada do método decorado, ao invés de estar invocando o método `__call__` do decorador, você estará invocando uma função. Sendo uma função, ela não espera a instância como primeiro parâmetro, contornando o problema apresentado, isso sem perder a referência a instância do decorador pois, como é uma *closure*, ela manterá referências do escopo em que foi definida, incluindo o `self` do seu decorador.

Para isso, você faz com que o próprio método `__call__` seja o decorador dos seus métodos:

```
class Decorator:
    def __call__(self, method):
        def wrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs):
            # Aqui você ainda pode utilizar self para acessar a instância do decorador
            return method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

Desta forma, quando você fizer `x.foo()` você estará invocando a *closure* `wrapper` definida pela classe `Decorator`, passando como primeiro parâmetro, `obj`, uma referência à própria instância `x`, gerando o resultado esperado.

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 123

    @Decorator()
    def foo(self):
        return self.__x

x = Teste()

print(Teste.foo(x))  # 123
print(x.foo())  # 123
```

Comment: Talvez consiga implementar soluções distintas utilizando o método `__new__` ou descritores, mas preciso analisar com mais calma em um momento de menor cansaço.

Comment: Vou testar isso amanhã com calma. De qualquer forma, sua resposta me parece muito boa, já tem o meu +1.

Comment: Bem, fiz uns testes e a sua solução resolve o que coloquei na perrgunta. No entanto, quando eu estava reduzindo o meu problema original para um MCVE, eu cortei os demais métodos do Decorator e com a solução proposta, eles tornam-se inacessíveis. A razão pela qual o Decorator era retornado ao invés de uma closure era para que tais métodos estivessem disponíveis. Conhece alguma solução para esse caso?

Comment: @VictorStafusa acessíveis de onde? Se for de dentro do decorador, mesmo dentro da closure voce consegue acessa-los. Até coloquei como comentário no código isso. Deu algum erro ao tentar reproduzir?

Comment: Acessíveis externamente como `x.foo.bar`. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou a resolver o problema, mas não o solucionou completamente. Depois de quebrar a cabeça por uns dias, cheguei na solução da resposta que postei aqui. Agradeço muito pela ajuda.